# SQL Server 2008 licensing - do I need an external connector license?

Tags: sql-server, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

I want to purchase a SQL Server 2008 license to run an ASP.NET website. I have a question about external connectors that you need to purchase in this case.

These are the specs of my production box Windows Server 2008 SP2 64 bit, **dual quad core 5570 processors**.

I understand from other postings that in this case I need a per processor license since there would be multiple users connecting to my website.

[SQL Server licensing, is it per CPU? So a 32 CPU would mean like 150K in licensing?](https://serverfault.com/questions/29018/sql-server-licensing-is-it-per-cpu-so-a-32-cpu-would-mean-like-150k-in-licensi/29143#29143)

My question is that even after you purchase per processor license, do you need to go ahead and get a external connector license?

TIA,
Raj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We asked this very question of our Microsoft LARS (Large Account Reseller) advisor, and the answer is 'if you have the per-processor licensing, then you do not need the external connector license'.

Nuff said really.

You will, however, need an external connector license for Windows itself.

Answer (score 2):

A SQL proc license is fine.

If you're users are known e.g. business partners it can be cheaper to stick with the CAL approach but you need to be able to demonstrate that you're controlling access to licensed users.

If these web users are only accessing the server to consume IIS services then I'm fairly sure that you don't need the connector license for your Windows box (just look at the Web edition as an example).  The connector is only when you've got an unknown quantity of users connecting to the server as a Terminal Server/File Server etc.

Comment: No, unless you use the web edition of Windows Server specifically, you need the external connector license to expose IIS to the general public - it replaces the requirement for CALs.

Again, something confirmed by our Microsoft LARS.

Comment: It's a grey area - I've had different answers from different resellers (as well as different people within Microsoft)

If you look at http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/licensing-faq.aspx#extconn in the sections 'When do I need to acquire a 2008 CAL?' and 'When do I need an EC license?' 
it states that you don't need a CAL when accessing through the internet annononymously i.e. a public web site.  It's only when you using Windows authentication that they argue for needing a CAL (or the Connector)